# Chrome emulator for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ipad, google-chrome, mobile

I have a mobile site which I developed in ASP.NET and I was wondering if anyone knows of any tools to test this on Chrome in an iPhone / iPad environment? This site has been functioning properly for awhile in every other browser on every other device, however there seem to be issues with it in this browser only on the iPhone / iPad. I just don't know how / if I can debug it somehow. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: pity I can vote you up only once! :)

Comment: haha. glad i am not the only one who has this need!

Comment: Got a Mac?  Searching last week, it seems like the only good iPhone emulator is available only on an Apple computer.  I've been looking, too.

Comment: @CMKanode the iPhone simulator on the mac doesn't allow you to install third-party applications such as Chrome.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295189/chrome-for-ios-user-agent-on-ipad

Comment: @jrturton  Thanks for that bit of info.  That's aggravating.  I inherited a Mac Mini, but haven't had the chance to use it (keyboard/mouse issues).

Answer (score 0):

You may find Adobe Shadow a helpful tool in this case: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/

Watch the [demonstration here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-technology-sneaks-2012/adobe-shadow), you'll see that you can debug your code like you would using the chrome dev tools itself.