# ASP.NET Webforms Doesn't Render Postback JavaScript Function for Chrome/iOS

Tags: asp.net, ios, google-chrome, .net-4.0, browser-detection

When we supply the user agent
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/21.0.1180.80 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3` to our .NET 4 webforms app, the script that defines the function __doPostBack is not present on the page and thus nothing that uses it works.

If we supply any other user agent string (say, Safari) it works fine. Can someone explain this?

Comment: This maybe the cause of the issue.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx and here is the Hotfix is here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: Yeah, after hours and hours we figured out that, that was the problem. The hotfix appears to be targeted at IE10 though. I'll post our .browser file below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the problem is that the Chrome user agent isn't recognized by .net and so it assumes that it's dealing with a low-level browser.

To solve, we added `~/App_Browsers/CriOS.browser` with the following contents:

```
<browsers>
    <browser id="CriOS" parentID="Safari">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="CriOS" />
        </identification>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser" value="CriOS" />
            <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
            <capability name="javascript" value="true" />
            <capability name="javascriptversion" value="1.7" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Worked perfect. My LinkButtons were not responsive in Chrome on iOS but now they are.