# In ASP.Net, Request.Browser.Browser & Request.Browser.MajorVersion is wrong for Chrome on iPad

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipad, ipad-2

I have to get current browser name & version of client browser. I am using `Request.Browser.Browser` for **Browser Name** and `Request.Browser.MajorVersion` for **Browser version**.

This is working good for all browsers except for chrome on iPad, where it shows Browser Name as ***Safari*** and version ***0***.

Any resolution for chrome on iPad?

Answer (score 1):

```
string agent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower()
```

Use the above to get all the browser and device information. You will see crios with the version number mentioned. That is the only way I have found to identify Chrome on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and added a check of the User Agent string for 'CriOS', which I found mentioned in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058670/1032196).

```
Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("crios", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

You could probably also use the index of 'CriOS' to get the version number that follows it in the user agent string.