# Unable to find Google Chrome browser information when application running in iPad

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad

I have written a JavaScript to check which browser my application is executed but when I run my application in iPad it is not finding the chrome browser. Can anyone help me on this? I am trying to run my application in iPad Chrome browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var browser;
    var yourVersion;
    var supportedVersion;
    checkBrowser();

    function checkBrowser() {
        var chrome = navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome\/([0-9]{2,}\.[0-9]*)");
        var ff = navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox\/([0-9]{2,}\.[0-9]*)");
        var ie = navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE\ ([0-9]{2,}\.[0-9]*)");

        if (chrome) {
            browser = "Chrome";
            yourVersion = chrome[1];
            supportedVersion = 35;
            if(chrome[1] < supportedVersion) {
                $("#browserVersionWarning").show();
            }
        } else if(ff) {
            browser = "Firefox";
            yourVersion = ff[1];
            supportedVersion = 31;
            if (ff[1] < supportedVersion) {
                $("#browserVersionWarning").show();
            }
        } else if(ie) {
            browser = "IE";
            yourVersion = ie[1];
            supportedVersion = 11;
            if (ie[1] < supportedVersion) {
                $("#browserVersionWarning").show();
            }
        } else {
            supportedVersion = 31;
            $("#yours").html(" ");
            $("#recommended").html("Firefox " + supportedVersion);
            $("#browserVersionWarning").show();
            return;
        }

        $("#yours").html(browser + " " + yourVersion);
        $("#recommended").html(browser + " " + supportedVersion);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: The current chrome browser in iPad doesn't have 'chrome' in their user agent string but it has CriOs for `Chrome Revision`. This might help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295189/chrome-for-ios-user-agent-on-ipad